# Technical limitations of a data-extracting VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, extract

Everyone !
it is my first post here and as a novice I hope my question will make sense. 
I'm a french intern working for a large firm and was assigned to the making of an "automated report" (I know, another one...).

The situation is pretty messy, each department generate reports for themselves with little to no constraints concerning the name, layout, size and data contained inside. (meaning that from one month to the other, each department may add or suppress an indicator, change the disposition of the data etc.)

I work for the performance and strategical division and need to create a four-table Excel file which would ideally be able to get the relevant data from the different files issued monthly. I cannot change the way files are updated on the intranet and my boss is clearly illiterate when it comes to computing.

Is it even possible for me (I do not know how to use VBA yet but I am a fast learner) to do this, while being transparent to her (zero or really easy manipulations), and adapting to the changing data-files format ?

Thank you in advance for any answer and sorry if i am not explaining myself properly. 
I wish you all a great day !
Jules

Answer (score 0):

In which formats would all the arbitrary files be?

In VBA you can open quite many file types and read the data if you just know the format and how data is organized.

If those files are in Excel files too, you can use Workbook.Open;

```
Dim wbReport As Workbook
Set wbReport = Workbooks.Open("ArbitraryDirectory\\ArbitraryfileName.xlsx")
```

Then use that workbook just like your main workbook;

```
OneOfYourFourTables.Cells([Row], [Column]) = _
   wbReport.Sheets("TheArbitrarySheet").Cells([Row], [Column])
```

Or use Range objects and/or Copy methods. (I generally like to loop around the Cells()).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the fast answer. It is only excel files, i'll try this method and see what comes out of it.

Comment: I do however have a little issue. Most of these files are Dynamic Cross Tables (I am not sure of the exact translation). When I change parameters, the [row],[column] addressing system does not work...

Comment: I would suggest you learn about working with sheets in VBA and think about the format/structure of the other excel files. Surely there is a way to programmatically find where the data you want is. In this case you say "does not work" without showing what you tried or how/why it didnt work. There is usually caption rows for data which remain static and provide easy anchor to search for.